# Are PPA’s searchable?

Tags: ppa

I would like to know if my PPA will be open to view by anyone who  searches in a database. If it's so, where is this database on the USPTO website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/newsletter/inventors-eye/provisional-patent-application-what-you-need-know):

> Further, because a PPA is not made public unless its application
> number is noted in a later-published application or patent, the
> failure by an applicant to file a nonprovisional application based on
> his/her PPA will not lead to public disclosure of his/her invention.